# No pysvn package in software center

Tags: software-center, package-management

There is a [pysvn package](https://launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/pysvn) but I can't find it in software center.

Any idea?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you want python-svn, which is in Universe.

http://packages.ubuntu.com/precise/python-svn

You may need to activate the Universe repository

[image: Universe]

See https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Repositories/Ubuntu for information on the repositories.

Comment: Hehum, I have that one installed. But i think that's not pysvn, which I compiled manually. I'm confused now, we have https://launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/pysvn, http://packages.ubuntu.com/precise/python-svn and http://pysvn.tigris.org/, and all of them appear to be a different thing. Where can I find doc for http://packages.ubuntu.com/precise/python-svn? I already developed app using pysvn, so I was looking if there is a package so I deploy it easier. Thanks.

Comment: If you look at the link I gave you , http://packages.ubuntu.com/precise/python-svn , it lists the home page as "pysvn.tigris.org" and the source code as "pysvn_1.7.5.orig.tar.gz" so it appears to be the same package, not sure if the version differs (from your ppa).

Comment: Yes, you are right. It works right from package, thanks! I don't know why I compiled it in the first place. Somehow I thought this package is some other svn library. Thanks again.

Comment: You are most welcome.